# "exists" in elasticsearch query not working on an object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I am attempting to perform an exists search, using Kibana Dev, but it is not working for embedded objects and I don't know why.

Here is an excerpt of the mapping:

```
{
  "myIndex": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "created": {
          "properties": {
            "firstName": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "lastName": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following exists query always returns nothing when I know it should:

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "created.firstName"
    }
  }
}
```

It is not nested so that's not the issue. If I substitute "id" for "created.firstName" it does work properly.

Using ES 7.4.0.

Comment: sorry, did you add index mapping for `created` fields after data was indexed? if yes then you have to reindex your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the search

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "created.firstName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If this does not return any results, you'll know you'll need to reindex.

---

Replication steps:

```
PUT ex
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "created": {
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST ex/_doc
{
  "id": 1,
  "created": {
    "firstName": "name"
  }
}

GET ex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "created.firstName"
    }
  }
}

DELETE ex
```